# In java, is there a chance a-b>0 and a>b different when a.b are both integer?

Tags: java

I want to know if these two lines have any different?

Is a>b better than a-b>0 , or the opposite, or they are same?

Comment: a-b>0 will make compiler calculate the value of (a-b) then make a compare. It's cost more than the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As integer has a range, so there is a chance these two are different if b is very small.

for example:

```
int a = 100;

int b = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

System.out.println(a - b > 0);//false

System.out.println( a > b);//true
```

a-b>0 will be false as a-b is larger than the max integer, so it overflows.

And a>b is true, of course.

So, I think a-b is better in some extreme cases.